# Ghostscript and PDF with fonts not embedded

Tags: fonts, ghostscript, raster

My system config is OS X with GhostScript 9.02
I would like to know (step by step) how to add and configure the file in GS that make possible to do substitutions for fonts.
My GS installation don't have installed/created the file.
How can I add it?

The problem is that I have One PDF with all embedded subset fonts, except one.
And for this one GS can't rasterize the page.

How is possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Please consider registering an account so you can leave comments and edit your posts.

Answer (score 3):

There are two categories of fonts in PDF -- "regular" fonts and CIDFonts. For regular fonts, only a single byte will be used for each glyph and there will be an Encoding and other information provided in the PDF to select the glyph from the font. Ghostscript will make a guess for a substitute font based on the FontName and while it may not look like the original, it should print.

CIDFonts, however are often accessed using multiple bytes, and the name implies some CMap needed for properly decoding the byte stream into a glyph number. The other 'gotcha' is that glyph numbers to particular glyphs will vary depending on the 'Ordering'. For CIDFonts that are not embedded, Ghostscript will produce error output like:

```
Can't find CID font "KozMin-Bold".
Substituting CID font /Adobe-Japan1 for /KozMin-Bold, see 
  doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Japan1" is not provided either. Will exit with error.
```

What this tells you is that the PDF referenced a font "Kozmin-Bold" that specified Ordering "Adobe-Japan1" and:

1) the Kozmin-Bold font was not found in Ghostscript's Resource/CIDFont directory

2) There was no mapping defined for Kozmin-Bold in the cidfmap file (GS searches for this file in any of the LIBPATH listed as 'Search Paths' from "gs -h".

3) There was no mapping for fonts with Adobe-Japan1 Ordering in the cidfmap. If Ghostscript can't find the font using steps 1 and 2, then it will substitute a font using the Ordering as the font name. At least this should get the correct glyph.

I don't want to reproduce the cidfmap documentation here since we update it on occassion, but it can be accessed online at:  http://www.artifex.com/gs-current-release/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution

Examples are provided in that section of the Ghostscript documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I process the PDF that has 1 font non embedded (Chinese STXihei CID font) I get the following error message (that is different from your example). **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name. GPL Ghostscript 9.02: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 The font is outside the trimbox (so, it's not important) but GhostScript is unable to rasterize the page.
I would like to know if there is a command to skip/substitute this font.
I have try to create the Fonts folder in:
/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.02/Resource/
An copy the font inside but the error appea

Comment: It sounds like you are not capturing all the output from Ghostscript. You are only getting the output to stderr, so you must be redirecting stdout elsewhere. That's why you don't see the remaining warnings.  You cannot skip fonts.  In order to define a substitute you must edit cidfmap as described in the documentation referenced above. copying fonts to the Fonts folder will not work at all for CIDFonts, which must be placed in the CIDFonts folder. If your build of Ghostscript has the resources built into the ROM file system, then you must tell GS to look for the fonts and cidfamp

Comment: You use the -I switch to do this.  I would suggest you create a convenient directory, make a sub-directory called 'CIDFont' and put the substitute font in there. In the upper directory create a cidfmap file which references that font and names it. Then use -I to include the upper directory in the search path.